# LsaCallAuthenticationPackage returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER 87 (0x57) when trying to purge a specific ticket

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, authentication, kerberos

I'm trying to purge a specific ticket from the cache,using LsaCallAuthenticationPackage.
I always get ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER 87 in the package status.
What could be the reason?
Here is my code (All other steps succeeded):

```
KERB_QUERY_TKT_CACHE_REQUEST tktCacheRequest = {
         KerbQueryTicketCacheMessage};

  void* pRep;
  DWORD cbRep;
  NTSTATUS pkgStatus;
  NTSTATUS s = LsaCallAuthenticationPackage(
                * hLsa, * nAuthPackage,
                &tktCacheRequest, sizeof tktCacheRequest,
                &pRep, &cbRep, &pkgStatus);
```

*pTktCacheResponse = (KERB_QUERY_TKT_CACHE_RESPONSE*)pRep;
for (ULONG i = 0; i < pTktCacheResponse->CountOfTickets; ++i)
    {
       KERB_TICKET_CACHE_INFO& ti = pTktCacheResponse->Tickets[i];
       if (/*Some condition*/)
       {
           KERB_PURGE_TKT_CACHE_REQUEST req;
           req.MessageType = KerbPurgeTicketCacheMessage;
           req.ServerName = ti.ServerName;
           req.RealmName = ti.ServerName;
           req.LogonId.HighPart = req.LogonId.LowPart = 0;

```
       NTSTATUS pkgStatus = 0;
       PVOID pReturnBuffer = NULL;
       ULONG nReturnedBufferLen = 0;
       NTSTATUS s = LsaCallAuthenticationPackage(
           hLsa, nAuthPackage,
           &req, sizeof (req) *2,
           0, 0, &pkgStatus);
       ULONG winErr = LsaNtStatusToWinError(pkgStatus);
   }
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kust use the memory allocation model as in the original Microsoft's klist (found in Microsoft Windows Platform SDK's samples), and got it works.

Thanks.